# SQL*Loader-704 and ORA-12154

Tags: sql-loader, oracle12c, tnsping

```
sqlldr "xxxx/xxxx@YYYYYXXXX" control=/home/local/INTERNAL/xxxxx/Presc_SQLLDR_File/Presc_SQLLDR.ctl log=/home/local/INTERNAL/xxxxx/Presc_SQLLDR_File/Presc_log.log data=home/achand/Presc_SQLLDR_File/Presc_SQLLDR.ctl
```

Whenever i'm trying to execute sqlldr I'm getting below error

```
SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I tried `tnsping YYYYYXXXX`

I got below error

> TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name

tnsnames.ora contain

```
DDCPPSD.WORLD =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXXXYYY)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = YYYYYXXXX)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Is DDCPPSD defined in your tnsnames.ora file, on the client machine you're running SQL\*Loader from?

Comment: Alex thanks for ur reply plz show above.

Comment: Does `tnsping ddcppsd.world` work then? If not maybe the file is in the wrong place, or TNS_ADMIN is pointing to the wrong place. Does your sqlnet.ora have a default domain entry?

Comment: Alex tnsping ddcppsd.world is working and sqlnet.ora have a default domain entry.

Answer (score 6):

This error message self-explainatory.
You have not specified the **connect string**, and just used username and password.
Therefore, Oracle tries to connect to local database.
You must specify **username/password@connect_string**, where **connect_string** is a name for the corresponding entry in your client side file **TNSNAMES.ORA** (same connect string you use in SQL Developer).

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after changing my password. I was using '@' as one of the special character in my password which was causing this issue. :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to do below changes in bat file.

**username/\"p@ssword\"@connect_string**

Enjoy.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read how to write a good answer. read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/338114) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

If your `tnsnames.ora` alias is defind as `DDCPPSD.WORLD` and your `sqlnet.ora` specifies a default domain of anything except `WORLD` then you need to fully qualify the alias when you use it:

```
tnsping DDCPPSD.WORLD
```

and

```
sqlldr xxxx/xxxx@DDCPPSD.WORLD control=...
```

Otherwise the default domain will be appended to the unqualified name, giving you a fully-qualified name that does not exist in your `tnsnames.ora`.

Read more about this [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF191).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. If you try to connect your server to your TNS , you will see you cannot connect.

```
telnet your_tns_ip your_tns_port
```

so you need to permition your server to TNS. That was my problem at least.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error too

```
SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

When I tryed call a batch like this...

```
sqlldr "uuuu/pppp@SSS"
```

I changed the batch file for:

```
set oracle_sid=SSS
sqlldr uuuu/pppp
```

After the change worked well.